# Preventing a child component from receiving focus when its parent gets it

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, focus

I have a composite component with several sub-components. When the user clicks on the parent component, it receives the focus, but then also one of its children gets it, which I'm not interested in occurring. Is there any way to prevent that or will the focus necessarily always be on an editable (sub-)component? Thanks.

Comment: ?When the user clicks on the parent component **WHAT** receives focus?  Only components that accept user input can receive focus.  Container components cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use some combination of the properties listed below. Note, in addition to the properties defined in the Flash API's, that Flex adds additional properties.

This topic is always a little confusing for me, and I usually experiment by enabling/disabling various properties.  I would imagine you need to do something like this:

```
parentComponent.tabChildren = false;
parentComponent.hasFocusableChildren = false;
// the above is probably enough, but you can also do...
childComponent.tabEnabled = false;
childComponent.focusEnabled = false;
childComponent.mouseFocusEnabled = false;
childComponent.tabFocusEnabled = false;
```

Here's a list of the mouse/keyboard focus related properties you might find useful:

- `mouseChildren` - Determines whether or not the children of the object are mouse, or user input device, enabled.
- `mouseEnabled` - Specifies whether this object receives mouse, or other user input, messages.
- `tabChildren` - Determines whether the children of the object are tab enabled.
- `tabEnabled` - Specifies whether this object is in the tab order.

The following only work in Flex:

- `focusEnabled` - Indicates whether the component can receive focus when tabbed to.
- `hasFocusableChildren` - A flag that indicates whether child objects can receive focus.
- `mouseFocusEnabled` - Whether you can receive focus when clicked on.
- `tabFocusEnabled` - A flag that indicates whether this object can receive focus via the TAB key This is similar to the tabEnabled property used by the Flash Player. This is usually true for components that handle keyboard input, but some components in controlbars have them set to false because they should not steal focus from another component like an editor.

Comment: Thank you, the `focusEnabled` property is what solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this in AS3 is through the tabEnabled property of the InteractiveObject.  Forget FLEX.

The tabEnabled property controls whether an InteractiveObject will receive the focus when clicked by the mouse and generate a mouseFocusChanged event.

I've implemented extremely elaborate focus changing mechanisms and tracking, and from my experience, it's best to use tabEnabled exclusively for controlling whether something can receive the focus via the mouse or tab key.

First, tabEnabled will be true by default for TextField's of type input, SimpleButtons, and Sprites/MovieClips with buttonMode = true.  So you're going to run into this default.  It's easier to respect it, than to remember when an where to override it.

Second, for custom objects that you want to receive the focus when clicked, tabEnabled is essentially the built-in property that controls both whether the tab key and a mouse click will assign focus to the object.  tabEnabled is actually a terrible name, because it really functions like "canReceiveFocusViaKeyboardOrMouse".  That's because any InteractiveObject instance can be assigned to stage.focus.  There's no way to disable an InteractiveObject from being assigned the focus, except to override the default behavior, so tabEnabled is what you want to work with.

Now, having said all that, you can easily override the default behavior by intercepting key_focus_change and mouse_focus_change events.

Mouse_focus_change is only dispatched to the object that currently has the focus.  Technically, the stage has the focus when nothing has the focus, so if you click something for the first time, the event will be generated with the stage as the target.  Likewise, if you click the stage, the focus will be set to null, but technically the stage is regaining the focus.

Key_focus_change functions similarly, except that when the stage has the focus, pressing tab will not tab to objects inside the flash player; either no focus change will occur, or other HTML controls will get the focus.  That's by design.  Meanwhile, if an object in the player does have the focus then then pressing tab will loop through the available tab enabled objects without ever returning to the stage.  That's also by design.  So for example, if you have only one tabEnabled object on the stage and it has the focus, pressing tab will not take the focus away from it.  It will actually loop the focus right back to itself and activate it's focusRect (since the source of the change was a key press).  You can turn off the key-change-activated focus rect on individual objects or globally on the stage.

Now the fun part.  I suggest you actually intercept and prevent the defaults of key_focus_change under certain circumstances, and implement your own key_down handler for the tab key.  For example, if you want your own subset of controls to receive the focus, intercept the key_focus_change event and see whether the object with the focus is one of your predefined objects.  If it is, then prevent the default, and allow your tab key press handler to move the focus to the next item in you loop.  You can also use this technique to walk up the parent chain until you find an object in your loop, assume that's losing the focus, and move the focus to the next item in your predefined focus loop.  In essense, you have the ability to make the tab key less fine-grained, ony focusing on a subset of focusable controls, by intercepting and either canceling or redirecting the focus change to an allowed parent.

### Side Note

Setting mouseChildren to false simply prevents children from being the target of a mouse event, so they still contribute to the hit area of their parent.  If the parent has mouseEnabled = false, then it will not receive mouse events (although as a child itself, it can still function as a hit area for a parent).  Setting mouseEnable = false and mouseChildren = false, it equivalent to setting mouseEnabled = false and setting every child's mouseEnabled property to false.  In other words, setting mouseChildren = false is simply a shortcut alternative to individiually setting every child object's mouseEnabled property to false.